# Hide the keyboard after having selected a value

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, keyboard

I'm working on a website that is full-tactil, and I display a virtual keyboard with autocompletion developped in jQuery. Once the name selected, I need to hide the keyboard. I tried with the `blur` function, but it didn't work.

You can see my code below :

```
$('#Nom')
.keyboard({ layout: 'qwerty' })

.autocomplete({
    source: liste, closeOnSelect:true, select: function (event, ui) {
        $("#NomVal").val(ui.item.id);     
        $('body > form > div > div.metro.single-size.login > button').html("Login <i class='icon-long-arrow-right'></i>");      
        $('body > form > div > div.metro.single-size.login > button').trigger('click');
        $('#Nom').blur();
    } 
})
// position options added after v1.23.4
.addAutocomplete({
    position : {
        of : null,        // when null, element will default to kb.$keyboard
        my : 'right top', // 'center top', (position under keyboard)
        at : 'left top',  // 'center bottom',
        collision: 'flip'
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are using jQuery Virtual Keyboard plugin from http://mottie.github.io/Keyboard/.

Inside the select Callback, get the keyboard instance an close it:

```
 function (event, selectedItem) {
    $(event.currentTarget).getkeyboard().close(true);
 }
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/egb3a1sk/787/